# How to connect a SQL server database in Pharo 6.1?

Tags: pharo

I try without success to conect to a SQL server database with Pharo 6.1 (Windows 
10 x64).

I have tried several things I've found around with no luck (DBXTalk among others).

This is the only thing that prevents me to use Pharo 6.1 in my company.

Thanks for your advices.

Edit : tried Pharo mailing list, Pharo Discord channels... No clues.

Comment: And what specifically are you having for issues?

Comment: I can't install the different packages because they aren't marked as valid Pharo 6 package (Pharo 5 at best) and when I try to install them nevertheless, I've got errors on installation ; I don't know where to find package installation error log in Pharo.